# Verify no exceptions were thrown in Spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I am brand new to Spock and perused their online docs. I have a test case where I need to verify that my fixture's interaction with a non-mock collaborator does *not* produce an exception:

```
class FizzSpec extends Specification {
    def "no exception thrown when we hail buzz"() {
        given:
        Fizz fixture = new Fizz()
        Buzz buzz = new Buzz("YES", true, "Garble barb") // A non-mock!

        when:
        fixture.hail(buzz)

        // TODO: How to verify the hail didn't produce an exception?
        // then:
        // thrown() == null
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: If you know the exception type, you can do `notThrown(NullPointerException)`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Found it.

You can use

```
noExceptionThrown()
```

To assert nothing was thrown

Comment: Here is the API definition http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/1.0/spock/lang/Specification.html#noExceptionThrown--

Comment: Do you write it after/before the statement that throws the exception? Or do you pass the statement as an argument to `noExceptionThrown()`?